# Merging same-indexed rows by taking non-NaNs from all of them in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sparse dataframe with duplicate indices. How can I merge the same-indexed rows in a way that I keep **all the non-NaN data** from the conflicting rows?

I know that you can achieve something very close with the built-in `drop_duplicates` function, but you can only keep either the **first** or the **last** row with the same index:

```
df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='first').set_index('index').sort_index()
```

What I'd need is all **non-nan values**, from any of the conflicting rows.

Before:

[image: DataFrame with A,B,C,D columns, and 1,2,2,3,4,5 rows. In the first 2-indexed row there is a 2.0 in the B column, in the second, there is a 3.0 in the D column.]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.reset_index().groupby('index').max()
```

This will select the non-NaN values from the conflicting rows. Or, if there are values in multiple conflicting rows for the same column, the maximum of them.